# Change MATLAB folder path

Tags: matlab

I have a general path

```
C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final.
```

However I don't know how can I change my MATLAB path to

```
C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final\Fingerprint
```

or

```
C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final\Image.
```

I know the `cd` command in MATLAB, but suppose that if this file is portable to other PC?
Could anyone guide me how can I change my directory in somehow that does not need the full address? Because I have classified my image, folders, files and code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `uigetfile` -- it opens a normal dialog box that lets the user select a file in any location.

Alternatively, if you are running a script and you know that the image(s) is (are) always located in the same spot *relative* to that script, you can use `fileparts` in combination with `mfilename('fullpath')` to get the full path to the running script, and then append the rest via string concatenation. Something like this:

```
scriptPath    = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
imageLocation = [scriptPath filesep 'Image' filesep];

img = imread([imageLocation 'your_image.jpg']);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly confident you can use relative paths with `cd`:

```
cd Fingerprint
```

And change back with

```
cd ..
```

Although I must ask - are you *sure* you want to be changing directories? Or should you instead be using relative paths when opening files?  (eg. `Image/foo.jpg`)